# regarding left shift and right shift operator

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

```
void times(unsigned short int time)
{
    hours=time>>11;
    minutes=((time<<5)>>10);
}
```

### Take the input `time` to be `24446`

The output values are

### hours = 11

### minutes = 763

The expected values are

### hours = 11

### minutes = 59

What internal processing is going on in this code?

Binary of `24446` is `0101111101111110`

`Time>>11` gives `01011` which means `11`.

`((Time<<5)>>10)` gives `111011` which means `59`.

But what else is happening here?

Comment: 24446 * 32 / 1024 = 763,9375, so 763 is the expected value of this code

Comment: What is your question? It is normal for `(24446<<5)>>10` to produce `763`.

Comment: what is the sizeof(int); in your machine

Comment: @kevingomes minutes = (time>>5)&0x3F; should work for each sizeof

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What else is going on here?

If `time` is `unsigned short`, there is an important difference between

```
minutes=((time<<5)>>10);
```

and

```
unsigned short temp = time << 5;
minutes = temp >> 10;
```

In both expressions, `time << 5` is computed as an `int`, because of integer promotion rules. [Notes 1 and 2].

In the first expression, this `int` result is then right-shifted by 10. In the second expression, the assignment to `unsigned short temp` narrows the result to a `short`, which is then right-shifted by 10.

So in the second expression, high-order bits are removed (by the cast to `unsigned short`), while in the first expression they won't be removed if `int` is wider than `short`.

There is another important caveat with the first expression. Since the integer promotions might change an `unsigned short` into an `int`, the intermediate value might be signed, in which case overflow would be possible if the left shift were large enough. (In this case, it isn't.) The right shift might then be applied to a negative number, the result is "implementation-defined"; many implementations define the behaviour of right-shift of a negative number as sign-extending the number. This can also lead to surprises.

---

Notes:

1. Assuming that `int` is wider than `short`. If `unsigned int` and `unsigned short` are the same width, no conversion will happen and you won't see the difference you describe. The "integer promotions" are described in §6.3.1.1/2 of the C standard (using the C11 draft):

   > If an `int` can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a
   >   bit-field), the value is converted to an `int`; otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned
   >   int`. These are called the integer promotions. All other types are unchanged by the
   >   integer promotions.

   Integer promotion rules effectively make it impossible to do any arithmetic computation directly with a type smaller than `int`, although compilers may use the `what-if` rule to use sub-word opcodes. In that case, they have to produce the same result as would have been produced with the promoted values; that's easy for unsigned addition and multiplication, but trickier for shift.
2. The bitshift operators are an exception to the semantics of arithmetic operations. For most arithmetic operations, the C standard requires that "the usual arithmetic conversions" be applied before performing the operation. The usual arithmetic conversions, among other things, guarantee that the two operands have the same type, which will also be the type of the result. For bitshifts, the standard only requires that integer promotions be performed on both operands, and that the result will have the type of the left operand. That's because the shift operators are not symmetric. For almost all architectures, there is no valid right operand for a shift which will not fit in an unsigned char, and there is obviously no need for the types or even the signedness of the left and right operands to be the same.

   In any event, as with all arithmetic operators, the integer promotions (at least) are going to be performed. So you will not see intermediate results narrower than an `int`.

Comment: I am glad to have a answer like this, but can you explain in a easy way, why integer promotion is occurring here?

Comment: @kevingomes: It always occurs. It is not optional. I added some more words to that effect.

Answer (score 3):

This piece of code seems to think that `int` is 16 bit and left shifting time would clear the top 5 bits.

Since you're most likely working in 32/64 bits, it doesn't happen if the value in `time` is a 16 bit value:

`time >> 5 == (time << 5) >> 10`

Try this:

```
minutes = (time >> 5) & 0x3F;
```

or

```
minutes = (time & 0x07FF) >> 5;
```

or

Declare `time` as `unsigned short` and cast to `unsigned short` after every shift operation since math is 32/64 bit.

24446 in binary is: `0101 1111 0111 1110`

- Bits 0-4 - unknown
- Bits 5-10 minutes
- Bits 11-16 hours

Comment: Well done interpreting the question. One might go as far as suggesting a portable replacement: `(time & 0x07FF)>>5`

Comment: will declaring time as `short int` solve the problem

Comment: size of `unsigned short int` is `2` byts, still the output is coming out to be `11` and `763`

Comment: your solution worked for me, but whats wrong with my statement?

Comment: The CPU does it's math in 32 or 64 bit. You'll need to add casting to unsigned short after every step. Ugly. Use the suggested methods instead for better portability

Comment: It is also possible that the compiler optimize minutes=((time<<5)>>10); to minutes=time>>5;

Comment: because of promotion to int, even if you declare minutes as `unsigned short`, the result still be wrong. The correct way should be `AND`ing and shifting

Comment: Fixed the answer to add the casting although it's not the preferred solution

Comment: @Manül Such an optimization, if `time` is of a 16-bit unsigned integer type, would be a compiler bug, since it changes the result of defined executions. While compiler have bugs, invoking a compiler bug should be the last resort.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that size of 'int' for the platform you working on 32 bits.
As far as processing is concerned assume that,
First statement is dividing "time" by '11'.
Second statement is multiplying "time" by 5 then dividing whole by 10.
Answer of your question ends here.

If you add what time value actually contains(number of seconds/miliseconds/hours or something else) then you may get more help.

Edit:
As @egur pointed out,you might be porting your code from 16 bit to 32/64 bit platform. 
A widely accepted C coding style to make the code portable is something like below:

make Typedef.h file and include it in every other C file,

```
 //Typedef.h

 typedef unsigned int   U16
 typedef signed int     S16
 typedef unsigned short U8
 typedef signed short   S8
    :
    :
 //END
```

Use U16,U8 etc. while declaring variables.

Now when you move to larger bit processor say 32 bit,Change your Typedef.h to

```
 //Typedef.h

 typedef unsigned int   U32
 typedef signed int     S32
 typedef unsigned short U16
 typedef signed short   S16
```

No need to change  anything in rest code.

edit2:

after seeing your edit:

```
  ((Time<<5)>>10) gives 111011 which means 59.
```

For 32 bit processors

```
   ((Time<<5)>>10) gives 0000 0010 1111 1011 which means 763.
```

Comment: Changing typedef doesn't help the code run if there are unportable constants in the code, for example `0x1 << 16` or `for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)`. And I don't think this is port code from 16 to 32 bit, if it must be done, it was ported decades ago. Also, there are `int32_t` and similar in `stdint.h`, no need to redefine

Comment: thanks for pointing,I work in embedded domain (small processors) so dint use stdint.h,The MISRA checker made me habit of writing  like this: hours=time>>(U16)11.Thanks again.

Comment: I know. I have had lots of trouble the time I worked with MISRA checker